# simple jquery append not working

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_sub_sid").on('click',function() { 
        var si = document.getElementById('sids').value; 
        var iPix = document.getElementById('iPix').value;   
        var urlI = document.getElementById('urlI').value;           
        if(si == ""){
            document.getElementById('valid_text_sid').innerHTML="Please enter valid Promo Code";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('valid_text_sid').innerHTML="";         
            $("#main_text_sid_contain").hide();
            $("#main_text_tick_contain").fadeIn(500);

            $("body").append("test");
        }
    });

    $("#main_text_sid_contain input").bind('keypress', function(e)  { 
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            var si = document.getElementById('sids').value; 
            var iPix = document.getElementById('iPix').value;   
            var urlI = document.getElementById('urlI').value;                       
            if(si == ""){
                document.getElementById('valid_text_sid').innerHTML="Please enter valid Promo Code";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('valid_text_sid').innerHTML="";
                $("#main_text_sid_contain").hide();
                $("#main_text_tick_contain").fadeIn(500);

$("body").append("test");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

This is a very simple jquery function.
But I dont know why $("body").append("test"); this simple body append function is not working.

can anyone please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Ok so now I have changed my code to

```
$("#btn_sub_sid").on('click',function() { 
    var si = $("#sids").val();
    var iPix = $("#iPix").val();
    var urlI = $("#urlI").val();
    if(si == ""){
        $("#valid_text_sid").html("Please enter valid Promo Code");
    }
    else{
        $("#valid_text_sid").html("");
        $("#main_text_sid_contain").hide();
        $("#main_text_tick_contain").fadeIn(500);
        $("body").append("test");
    }
});
```

but still isnt working.

Comment: is it going to else part?

Comment: Why the horrible mix of jQuery and DOM?

Comment: yes its going to else part.

Comment: could you provide the html you're using as well? preferably in a jsfiddle together with the javascript

Comment: sorry. I cant provide the html.

Comment: don't use getElementByID if you are using jQuery. You can simply use $('#element input') to select.there is problem with the getting id data...if you cann't provide us the html try to see the problem in web developer tool.

Comment: do you mean
var si = document.getElementById('sids').value; 
this is when the problem is?

Comment: 1) do you HAVE a body tag 2) try $("body").prepend("<div>test</div>");

Comment: Hello All, thanks for your reply. Now body.append is working but its not visible on the page.
any ideas.

Comment: Not without seeing the page